# How to create aopProxy in real-time?

Tags: proxy, javabeans, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-annotations

Spring component

```java
@Component
public class Component {
    public String service(){
        return new SubClass(arg1, arg2);
    } 
}
```

Spring AOP aspect

```java
@Component 
@Aspect
public class Logger{
   @Around("excution(* Component.*(..))")
   public Object service(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // to-do
   }
}
```

Spring *context.xml*

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="kr.co.vpay.tr"></context:component-scan>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

I want to create SubClass as proxy, When call service() after Component created

How to do?

Comment: Example code shared will not compile. `Component.service()` is declared to return `String` but returning an instance of `SubClass`. Could you please update the question with the purpose of having a proxy for the object returned from `Component.service()` ?

Comment: oh! i am mistake.

@Component
public class Component {
    public String service(){
        return new SubClass(arg1, arg2).process();
    } 
}

Comment: I use spring version 3.2.3

Comment: What do you intend to do after creating a proxy for the returned `object` ? Also `String` is a final class which cannot be proxied. If you share your requirement to proxy , probably someone can help you with a better solution than proxying .